# Href on input box is not working

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, inputbox

I am trying to link a input box with a url given but its not currently working on my site...

I have tried with two piece of codes but both are not working...

1st:

```
<a href="http://google.com">
<input name="category" id="category" type="text" value="example" style="cursor:pointer;"  readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" /></a>
```

2nd:

```
<input name="category" id="category" type="text" value="example" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="location.href ='http://google.com'" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" />
```

Any solution to that ?

Comment: use `window.location.href` and remove `disabled`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input name="category" id="category" type="text" value="example" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.location.href ='http://google.com'" readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's marked as disabled, so the `onclick` won't trigger.